# Sys.argv not returning expected value in node with child_process data send to python script within node app

Tags: python, node.js, child-process, sys

I have a nodejs app, and am using `child_process` to send data to be run in a python script. However, `"sys.argv"` only returns `"script1.py"`, the file name, rather than the object I want to send to python.

Here is my nodejs:

```js
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
    console.log('hi')
  var dataToSend;
  var nodeData = "jeff";
  console.log('breh')
  var obj = {obj1: image3v, obj2: image4v}
  const python = spawn('python', ['script1.py'], obj);
  console.log('welp')
  python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    dataToSend = data.toString();
  });
  
  python.stderr.on('data', data => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
    console.log(data)
  })
  
  python.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log('exited')
    console.log(dataToSend);
    //run new stuffhere
  });
})
```

My script1.py:

```python
import sys

print('python begins')
print(sys.argv[0])
print(sys.argv[0][1])
print(sys.argv[0][2])
print(sys.argv)
print(sys.orig_argv)
```

However, all of these print statements in python print either `'script1.py'`, `['script1.py']`, or one of the letters in script1.py via the `[0][1]`, etc. If I try to do `sys.argv[1]`, I get index out of bounds.

Looking at other references, my code should be working, but I think there's something I'm not seeing. I don't know what else to try to access the object.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this do any better? `const python = spawn('python', ['script1.py', obj]);`

Comment: You can only pass strings as parameters to a process being spawned (and you have to do so as part of the list passed as the second parameter to `spawn()`; you're passing `obj` as the `options` parameter, instead).  To pass a more complex object as a parameter, you're going to have to stringify it somehow (convert to JSON, perhaps) - the best way would likely depend on exactly what `image3v` and `image4v` are.

Comment: @rickhg12hs it worked! I tried everything but that. Could you post that as the answer so I can mark it as such. Though, now it returns [object Object], and my getattr isnt working, '..has no attribute obj1' when I do
print(getattr(x, 'obj1')
And obj1 is the first param of the object. The object itself is {obj1: "jeff"}

Comment: No time for a proper answer at the moment, but here's a quick answer. Use `const python = spawn('python', ['script1.py', JSON.stringify(obj)]);` and in the python program, `loaded_arg = json.loads(sys.argv[1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `spawn` an external command and pass arguments on the commandline, the arguments need to be serialized, for example, to a string.  There are limits to the size of commandline arguments, so if they are too large, some other method must be used (e.g., passing via stdin/stdout, named pipes, etc.).

Here's a demonstration of passing arguments from node to python.

`spawnSO.js`:

```js
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');

const params = {"fred": 1, "wilma": "wife", "dino": ["barks", 2.718]};

const python = spawn('python', ['spawned.py', JSON.stringify(params)]);

python.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

python.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

python.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

`spawned.py`:

```python
import sys

print(sys.orig_argv)
print("len(sys.argv): ", len(sys.argv))

for k, arg in enumerate(sys.argv):
  print(f"argv num: {k}, argv: {arg}")

import json

from_json_string = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
print(f"type of converted JSON: {type(from_json_string)}, loaded value: {from_json_string}")
```

Here's the output:

```
$ node spawnSO.js
stdout: ['python', 'spawned.py', '{"fred":1,"wilma":"wife","dino":["barks",2.718]}']
len(sys.argv):  2
argv num: 0, argv: spawned.py
argv num: 1, argv: {"fred":1,"wilma":"wife","dino":["barks",2.718]}
type of converted JSON: <class 'dict'>, loaded value: {'fred': 1, 'wilma': 'wife', 'dino': ['barks', 2.718]}

child process exited with code 0
```

Comment: Thanks! One thing though, I am getting the too large param error. How would I use one of the other methods you suggested? I am attempting to send an image file, so its quite thick

Comment: @blueberrr Looking at other SO Qs/As, and Googling, there seem to be a lot of examples of using sockets, etc.  Perhaps the easiest way might be to write the JSON string to a file, pass the filename (on the commandline) to the python program, and then just read the file.  You have a lot of options.  If you have a problem implementing a solution, a new question would probably be appropriate.